# How to know the range of ip addresses used by Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, ip

I'm planning to deploy a node app on Heroku. The database is a Mongo Atlas cluster. Because Heroku use dynamic IP addresses, I need to either allow all ips to access the mongo cluster, or only a specific range, which would be more secure.

Basically, I'll need to write something like: `192.168.1.1/32` in my Mongo cluster instead of `0.0.0.0/0`.

But how to know the range Heroku will use? I'm planning to use an European server. I've also checked AWS' list: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json but I just can't figure how to know the range I need to specify. `eu-west` ips are so different, there is no pattern here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how did you go with this?

Comment: I have allowed all ips, but I have a hardcore password. The only solution to get a dedicated ip address on heroku is to pay more money.

Comment: did you try using an addon like fixie or quotaguard?

Comment: No because it slows the connection speed. I preferred to keep a lighting fast response time. Also, I don't own 100% of these addons code, so I don't want to have any issue in the future (they could stop maintenance, or there could be a security issue, etc).